# Using radiobuttons in mvc webgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button, webgrid

I have a WebGrid on my form, inside that I have a column called 'duration'. In this column I'm displaying 2 radio buttons, so the Admin should select one validity period for that user on every row, either 30 days or 90 days and submit. And here I want to get the selected radio button value submitted value and the Id of that row so that I can perform the database activities with that values.

```
 grid.Column("Duration", format: @<text><div style="width: 30em"><table><tr><td><input       type="radio" name="group1" value="30"> 30 Days<br>
</td><td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="90"> 90 days<br>
</td></tr></table></div></text>)))
```

Here the problem is when I'm giving the same group name the radio buttons we can only select one radio button in the entire grid, but how I want is that he should select one radio button on each row. Also how can retrieving be done?

Answer (score 0):

A separate name should be used for each 'group' of radio buttons.  Out of all radio buttons that have the same name, only one can be selected.

With MVC, you can use model binding; when your form posts back, the model is built and the properties are assigned based on the name or id values.

To use this, you need to create inputs using methods such as:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.MyProperty) @* ... *@
```

***********   edit -- clearer explanation   *********************************
Let's use two 'groups.'  A user can select a first name and an occupation.  To limit the number of selections within a group, each control group needs its own value for the radio button's 'name' property.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.NameSelected, "Jane", New With { .name = "UserName" }) Jane <br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.NameSelected, "Jack", New With { .name = "UserName" }) Jack <br />



@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.Occupation, "Lumberjack", New With { .name = "Occupation" }) Lumberjack <br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.Occupation, "Waiter/Waitress", New With { .name = "Occupation" }) Waiter/Waitress
```

The radio buttons for the names will now be selectable without affecting the radio button selections in the occupation group, and vice versa.

Comment: sorry for my lameness,but i did not get it right....pls if dont mind can u little more clear...how can i give separate name for a group of 2 radiobuttons on each row? as the group name should be changing on every new row